# Would you use “ergo“ as a synonym to hence, therefore etc. in an essay?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, difference, conjunctions

Specifically in the CAE exam. I´m not sure if the examinars will be too fond of this expression

Comment: Welcome to ELL pabloe.  As a general rule we do not answer questions that would be entirely opinion based.  Whether or not an examiner would be fond of the word *ergo* cannot be determined without very precise, clearly illustrated context.  I am suggesting that we close this question as being opinion based.

Comment: ok cool i guess thx

Comment: Do you have an example of how you intend to use the word?  A complete sentence or paragraph, and the general context would be helpful.

Comment: @EllieK I second this thought, though I feel like the mention of examiners was just providing context and not integral to the question. I suggest that the question could be improved by editing to ask more about what kind of context "ergo" is useful and appropriate in (or not), and focus less on this specific exam.

Comment: What is an 'examinar'?

Answer (score 5):

"Hence" works, though the literal Latin meaning is "thus." Since we do in fact have the word "thus" (and other words and phrases to the same effect), there's little reason to use it.

Using "ergo" in casual conversation creates a tone of scholarly learnedness. This would often be done playfully, for humor ("I can't find my shirt anywhere I looked. Ergo, it must actually be where it belongs, in the closet."). Using it seriously runs the risk of sounding pretentious or presumptive, unless you are actually deep into a complicated statement of scholarly logic.

Even "thus" is a bit elevated in tone. Other replacements include "as a result," "considering this," etc.